# Webpack 2 Angular 1 template loader?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack-2

Since webpack 2 introduced ES6 module system, `require('./mytemplate.html')` syntax isn't working in an angular 1 and webpack 2 based project.

Unable to find a loader which works with webpack 2 to load html templates.

What is the right way to load angular 1 template files using webpack2?

Note: I am using typescript classes to create angular 1 components, which have template: require('./mytemplate.html') property. As an example.

```
export class MyComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    public template: string = require('./mytempalte.html');
    public controller = MyControllerClass;
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I guess it's possible to use the same loader, just instead of assigning template contents to some object property try to import in in a variable, which will be assigned to object property. Like `import template from './template.html'`. And then `someObject.template = template;`.

Comment: I tried importing like:
import template from './mytemplate.html';, but it gives error because it cannot recognise html template. I have updated question to mention that I am using typescript too.

Comment: It looks, that they recently added this feature (https://github.com/webpack/html-loader/pull/97), but they haven't made an updated relese in npm yet. So I think you either have to wait or to have your own locally build version of this webpack loader.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand what this pull request is doing. with that pull request, will require('./mytemplate.html') syntax work or we will have to import the html differently? I have asked on that github stream as well.

Comment: According to the pull request description it looks, that it's possible to configure html loader to load html using es6 modules. So it should resolve your problem once new version of that loader will be released.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will update this answer once its is released if someone encounters this.

Comment: @Nexus23 could you update the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To date webpack 2 still supports require syntax. What worked for me was to install node typings:

```
@types/node
```

This eliminates errors I was having when requiring tempaltes e.g

```
export class AdminComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    public template: string = require('./admin.component.html');
    public controller = AdminComponentController;
}
```

Still using html-loader to load these templates though.

Comment: Yep, but for not rewriting your existent code you can try any loader (just trying by myself not sure it will work) https://github.com/WearyMonkey/ngtemplate-loader , that will process this strings for you (so you won't need to add require or even ngtemplate! inside your templateUrl).